# SASS Mixins to Animate Dropdown Opening

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I have a series of Nav dropdowns.  When the user hovers over one of them, I want it to open using an animation.  So my HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="nav-dropdown-contents short-dropdown">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
</div>

<div class="nav-dropdown-contents medium-dropdown">
  <div>Item A</div>
  <div>Item B</div>
  <div>Item C</div>
  <div>Item D</div>
</div>
```

So short dropdown has 2 items, and medium dropdown has 4.

Here is my SCSS for the short dropdown:

```
.short-dropdown {
    &.open {
        animation-name: shortDropdownOpenAnimation;
        animation-duration: 400ms;
    }

    &.closed {
        animation-name: shortDropdownCloseAnimation;
        animation-duration: 400ms;
    }
}
```

And I have the two animations defined thusly:

```
@keyframes shortDropdownOpenAnimation {
from {
    height: 0px;
}

to {
    height: 50px;
}
```

}

```
@keyframes ShortDropdownCloseAnimation {
from {
    height: 50px;
}

to {
    height: 0px;
}
```

}

So this works great, but now I also have to define keyframes for my medium dropdown.  And as I get more dropdowns with different numbers of items, it would be nice to be able to factor all of these mixins out into just one, that takes a height property that I can pass in.

I've seen numerous examples of how to use mixins with animations, but they are all kind of verbose, and allow you to animate any properties.  I just need to animate height.  That's it.  I'm looking for the simplest possible way to do that.

Thanks.

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner wrapper and apply any animations to that:

https://jsfiddle.net/v3act47k/1/

```
.dropdown {
   transition: all ease 1s;

  .inner-wrap {
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    visibility: hidden;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
  &:hover {
    .inner-wrap {
      animation-name: slideInDown;
        animation-duration: 400ms;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes slideInDown {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could change the animation to max-height like this:

```
@keyframes dropdownOpenAnimation {
  from {
      max-height: 0;
  }

  to {
      max-height: 300px;
  }
}
```

the problem is that the small dropdown animation will be faster than the big one. You should change the animation time to achieve the same feeling on both objects.